# how to create href within for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help to make this code within a for loop. Thank you

```
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[x].code);' >" +
mysecObj.data[x].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
```

below is the code:

```
document.getElementById("act" + i + j).innerHTML = myfirstObj.data[i].items[j].name +  " " +
  "<div class='dropdown'  id='" + i + j + "' onclick='display_cell(this.id)' style='text-decoration:underline;color:blue;'>" + 
   myfirstObj.data[i].items[j].remark  + " " + 
   "<div class='dropdown-content' >" + 
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[0].code);' >" + "mysecObj.data[0].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[1].code);' >" + "mysecObj.data[1].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[2].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[2].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[3].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[3].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[4].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[4].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[5].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[5].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[6].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[6].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[7].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[7].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[8].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[8].code + "</a>" + "<br>" +
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[9].code);' >" + mysecObj.data[9].code + "</a>" + "<br>" + 
"</div>" + "</div>";
```

Comment: So you're question is, how to write a for-loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Possible you need to change from

```
"<a href='javascript:sel_val(mysecObj.data[0].code);' >"
```

to

```
"<a href='javascript:sel_val("+mysecObj.data[0].code+");' >"
```

Because you don't add full code, so I just can recommend that. And it's true if and only if sel_val function return a string, because href='need to be a string here'

Comment: I need the syntax in variable like mysecObj.data[x].code